# Find substring in dataframe in R

Tags: r, substring

There have been many posts about finding a column or row name with a certain substring in R, however I am looking for a way to identify every row/column combination (i.e. data entry) with a specific substring. For example:

```
ID  comment_1              comment_2      comment_3
1   brake pad replaced     front brake    engine check
2   diagnostic performed   oil change     brake light
```

I want it to return row 1, column 2 &3, row 2 column 4.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to do this without a loop

Comment: which subsring are you looking for? `brake`???

Comment: `which(array(grepl("\\bbrake\\b",as.matrix(dat)),dim(dat)),T)`??

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: thanks @Onyambu! @RonakShah I was hoping to get either a list of rows and columns where this works.

Comment: Then @Onyambu 's comment is the answer.